# Need help in downloading PDFs from arxiv dataset which is in kaggle

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science, data-analysis

I am seeking assistance with downloading PDFs from the arxiv dataset, which is available on Kaggle, onto my local file system. Ideally, I am looking for a code that allows users to input the subject name and the number of PDFs to download. If anyone has any suggestions or resources to share, it would be greatly appreciated. **Here is the link to the arxiv dataset on Kaggle: **https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/1b6883fb66c5e7f67c697c2547022cc04c9ee98c3742f9a4d6c671b4f4eda591.

I have tried scraping the arxiv website to download PDFs. I was able to scrape all the data and even download some of the PDFs. For example, when I entered the subject name as "Machine Learning" and the number of PDFs to download as 200, only 16 PDFs were properly downloaded, while the rest were either 0kb or 3kb in size. However, when I checked the website, the PDFs were around 4mb in size.

Upon researching a solution to this problem, I discovered that bulk data access on the arxiv website is not possible due to a robot that detects automatic tasks and blocks them to avoid overloading and traffic to the website. Since millions of users access the site at a time, there is no way to access the data in bulk. As an alternative, I found that the mirror site of the main site, which is the arxiv Kaggle dataset, is updated by arxiv itself once a week. This dataset can be accessed to download PDFs.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps with the arxiv API: https://info.arxiv.org/help/api/
or python library https://pypi.org/project/arxiv/ to search document including a keyword and scrape the document id.
After: [https://arxiv.org/pdf/{id}](https://arxiv.org/pdf/%7Bid%7D) to download the document

Or following the instruction in Kaggle:
"The full set of PDFs is available for free in the GCS bucket gs://arxiv-dataset or through Google API (json documentation and xml documentation).
You can use for example gsutil to download the data to your local machine.

List files:

```
gsutil cp gs://arxiv-dataset/arxiv/
```

Download pdfs from March 2020:

```
gsutil cp gs://arxiv-dataset/arxiv/arxiv/pdf/2003/ ./a_local_directory/
```

Download all the source files

```
gsutil cp -r gs://arxiv-dataset/arxiv/  ./a_local_directory/
```